# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client in stripe

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I'm setting up a stripe webhook to check if the payment intent was successful or not. But while doing so, I'm getting this error `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client in stripe`, what am I doing wrong in the route?

```
import express from 'express';
import Stripe from "stripe";
const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, { apiVersion: "2020-08-27" });

const router = express.Router();

router.post(
    "/webhook",
    express.raw({ type: "*/*" }),
    async (request, response) => {
        const sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"];

        let event;

        try {
            event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
                request.body,
                sig,
                process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET_KEY
            );
              console.log("type", event);
        } catch (err) {
            //   console.log("type2", err);
            response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
        }

        response.json({ received: true });
    }
);

export default router;
```

Comment: Seems to be a stripe error, did you try to only write in response response.json({ received: true }); (commenting the strie part)

Comment: Yeah I just did comment out the stripe part. I am getting `Cannot POST /stripe/webhhook` but when I changed the method to GET, I am getting the response: true. What could be the issue?

Comment: Hi, why did you deleted this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237545/cannot-set-properties-of-undefined-setting-gtag/74252569#74252569

Comment: @kissu it wasn't working

Comment: @kibakoriasu not a viable reason to delete it tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a section here https://stripe.com/docs/identity/handle-verification-outcomes that skips the body parsing if the url points to the webhook service

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.originalUrl === '/webhook') {
    next();
  } else {
    bodyParser.json()(req, res, next);
  }
});
```

That could be the issue: webhook expects you not to execute `express.raw()` if you're going to give him the `request.body` to analyse

Comment: doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send a json response with `response.json()` after the error handling sends the 400 response with `response.status(400).send()` -- you can't do that.

You need to either move your `response.json()` to the end of the `try` block or have the `catch` block `return` (as @abhishek noted) to stop the execution.

Answer (score -1):

In the catch block you are not returning.

```
catch (err) {
            //   console.log("type2", err);
            return response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
        }
```